# Flutter: Lost connection to device

Tags: flutter, crash, connection, runtime-error

I am working on a recipe app which include different kind of recipes whose data is stored in **Json files** in the app and I had 8 different categories of screens when I completed my UI and started adding more food items in the **json files** then suddenly I faced the problem **Lost connection to the device** though through my flutter doctor command there is no fault in the flutter and dart neither any problem in the code still the app crashes again and again whenever I view the newly added items screen. Any kind of help is appreciated. ?????

I tried different articles in the Stackoverflow and tried adding some gradle  configs from the stack overflow question answer but it didn't solved my problem.

Comment: You can check the logcat for the cause of your crash

Comment: Thanks bro but the error itself resolved by now if it happens again I'll surely check the logcat.